# How to use an Image-map with an image-sprite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a sprite of buttons that I want to use for my website (https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/epson/images/epson_buttons.png), 
and I was wondering if it is possible to set a section of each button to open up a drop down menu.

This may get a bit confusing but, for each button, when you hover over the entire button I have a hover image in the sprite, but I want to distinguish between clicking the arrows on each button and the button itself. So the arrows will bring a drop down menu and the button will take you to an overview page.

How can I go about doing this? haven't been able to find anything with nearly enough information to help me out.

Comment: You can't use image maps on background images.

Comment: The easy and right way to do this would be with multiple elements, one for the main button, and one for each arrow or whatever you intend to click.

Comment: No, but you could use a background image on a “blank”, transparent image.

Comment: @RasoolGhafari how would that work?

Comment: @Paulie_D right, I had figured that out, but was hoping there was some way around that. Would it be possible to use a sprite with <img> tags?

Comment: adeneo, was hoping to avoid that
@CBroe can you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: `was hoping to avoid that`... but it's far easier than what you are trying to do as well as far more common practice

Comment: @charlietfl right, I know that, but my goal here is to limit HTTP requests thus making everything faster. The span idea is what, as of now is working the best for me, and saves me the time of making separate images for every single button and aspect of the button. In the end I will have around 6 buttons, with 3 different looks to them, so that would turn out to be 36 HTTP requests as opposed to 1.

Comment: no I think you misinterpreted what was suggested. multiple elements doesn't imply not using your sprtite. Is essentially same concept I gave you as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach would be put a child in the link, if child is clicked... open dropdown, if not follow link

Position and size the child accordingly

```
<a class="buttonClass" href="foo.html"><span class="toggleDropdown"></span></a>
```

jQUery

```
$('a.buttonClass').click(function(e){
   if( $(e.target).is('.toggleDropdown') ){
         /* prevent href being opened*/
          e.preventDefault()
         /* run dropdown code here */            
   }
})
```

User wouldn't see child as it would be transparent

Comment: so I would have to position the span so that it is over the toggle arrow?

Comment: So the next thing that I would have to work around would be the hover issue. If the span is over the button, I'm assuming that when my mouse would be over it (the span) the hover option for the button wouldn't work. Is there a work-around for this? like use the hover option for the span? the only thing with that is that it would negate me being able to click the button...but what if I use a z-index for the hover so the span would still be positioned over it?

Comment: why wouldn't hover work? When you hover the span you haven't left the parent. You are trying to make it too complicated. No need to worry about z-index either

Comment: Here's a very crude demo . I wasn't going to spend time getting sizes and positions exact  http://jsfiddle.net/pN7A8/1

Comment: so what about having different hovers? one for the button and one for the drop down

Comment: you can certainly. I went for simplest case

Comment: So this is actually working out really well thank you. I am pretty good at Javascript, but my jQuery knowledge is pretty limited (all I have done is persistent scroll bars and stuff) so where would a good place be to look for help with using jQuery to show and hide things? because I want it to act like a normal drop down menu, so the user can close it back up if they wanted to.

Comment: jQuery API has examples for every method and is a great resource. Go through it some time. Lots of tutorials on web for simple events like you are asking about

Comment: So here is the site with the buttons that I am working on: https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/epson/home.aspx Receipt is the button that I am using for my testing, but I was thinking about making separate functions for each button, or is that unnecessary/the wrong thing to do?

Comment: what do you mean different functions? Dropdown should be able to be done in one function for all. I believe you are overthinking it

Comment: I probably am, but thats just because I really don't know jQuery very well. Let me kind of outline what my idea is:
I am going to use toggleClass() for each of the buttons, so that all menus could be displayed at the same time. So would I have to do something like    `$('#homeButton').click(function(){...`  for each button?

Comment: no...use more generic selector....then insiide handler do `$(this).parent().find('someElement').doSomehting()`. this will isolate within each LI

Comment: Ok, so do get a bit more specific... would it look something like `$("span").click(function() {
$(this).parent().find('#homeButton).toggleClass('someClass') etc..`
or am I overthinking this again?

Comment: no...something like `$('.epsonNav a').click(function(){ $(this).toggleClass('className'); })`

Comment: I thought I almost had it! but then I realized, I am not trying to change the way the button looks, I am trying to show the drop down menu for receipt or whatever it is...so I am thinking that I need a few `if` statements to figure out what `this` is and then toggle the class of the corresponding `ul` to show it. Does that seem like the first right thing I've said? :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can all you need to do is tweak the elements inside each button, in my case i use `a` and `div ul` please review this demo

**http://jsfiddle.net/BFWQa/13/**

and ask any question if it's what you expected.

Comment: Thats actually almost right on target. The way I have it now is that when you hover over the button it goes to the white version of it... does that hover have any effect on the outcome?

Also, if instead of a hover menu, I would like to have javascript code so then when the arrow is clicked it brings up that menu, instead of when you hover, so is this still possible?

Comment: yes it's possible it's just the demo you need to work around this as a solution and better with jquery you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use from `background-image` and `background-position` rules of `CSS`. for more details check [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) link.

*Please voteup it or/and mark it as answer if it helped you.*

Comment: So I already have my sprite set up. I am trying to figure out if there is some way that I can map the button so that when it is click in a certain area, different things happen